# I'm trying to remember a word that means 'to add' to something and maybe also means 'to alter' something by adding to it

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I think at least part of the meaning is 'to add' and maybe another part of the meaning is 'to alter'. 
I'm sure is spelt using the letter 'x'.

I remember reading the word a while ago. I'm quite sure I was reading about the 'Siege of Jerusalem' and the word was used to say that more people were added to the populace of the city after it was conquered by their kingdom.

Comment: *Expand* or *extend*, maybe?

Comment: You don’t mean *exaggerate*, do you?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. The following is the strict rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You're looking for *amend*.

Comment: @deadrat I don't get the joke. One cannot "amend" the population of a city with immigrants after a siege. And of course *amend* doesn't contain the `x` OP is "sure it's spelt with". If I were going to suggest random "A" words, disregarding the `x` constraint, I think the best candidate would be *augment*.

Comment: @DanBron No joke, I just misread the letter and, I'm afraid, I disregarded the example.  Even assuming that the OP meant *populace*, *alter* makes little sense in that context.  But my fault.  When you amend a document, you add to it and generally alter its meaning.  *Augment* doesn't have an *x* either.  Perhaps *annex*?

Comment: *increment*....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the context, I guess the word you are looking for is   [Annex / Annexed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/annex).

Which means:

1. To append or attach, especially to a larger or more significant thing.
2. To incorporate (territory) into an existing political unit such as a country, state, county, or city.
3. To add or attach, as an attribute, condition, or consequence.

Source: [TFD]

Comment: Thank-you so much for your responses! I'm not sure I'll ever remember the word but I've learned 'annex' and 'augment' which are very suitable words. Yes I did mean 'populace' thank-you for correcting me on that. My memory is being jogged. I remember this much: The word means to grow larger by something attaching to it - in this context a group of people and/or section of land being added - and the word is usually pertaining to capturing territory. I'm still unsure but if you're still interested I'm eager for answers!

Comment: Annex:
2. to incorporate (territory) into the domain of a city, country, or state:
Germany annexed part of Czechoslovakia.                                                       - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/annex?s=t                                                       I think it must have been 'Annex'. You've helped very much thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

### [**Population explosion**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/population+explosion)

It describes a sudden, large increase in the size of a population.

Maybe this is what you saw because it does have that "x" sound.

> The geometric expansion of a biological population, especially the unchecked growth in human population resulting from a decrease in infant mortality and an increase in longevity.

Comment: How about expansion?

Comment: I believe both refer to a general increase in population, not quite what OP is asking for. The second paragraph sets the context.

Comment: @spyky_42 What am I missing here? Second paragraph says "adds more people". Can you help?

Comment: Well, the first paragraph certainly points to an increase in population. The second one sets the context by saying that the increase happened due to war/siege. So I thought Annexed would be more suitable. I might be wrong, just my thought process.

Comment: @spyky_42 I understand *annex*. It also means to "add something" in general. I think after the conquest, civilisation developed better living standards and hence a rise in population. Maybe we're equally right.

Comment: Btw, when you "add" to something, it also gets "altered", doesn't it?

Comment: I'm fairly sure adding to something means it's altered which was difficult for me to comprehend initially. I think it's not a common understanding of the word 'add'.

Comment: @Stephen So did you get the correct word?

Comment: @NVZ Yes I did, thank-you. It is 'annex'.